# Cancellation Token not performing the cancel action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, cancellationtokensource, cancellation-token

I have a async method where i'm declaring a cancellation token,but whenever i click the cancel button and post to my cancelrequest controller,the _tokenSouse IsCancellationRequested does not turn to true instead my task keeps running,the model returned so currently is empty,i'm just trying to test the cancelation token using task.Delay,what could i be doing wrong,Please see code below.

```
//global variable in controller
        private CancellationTokenSource _tokenSource = null;

   [HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Trace(TraceModel model)
        {
            _tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
            var token = _tokenSource.IsCancellationRequested;

            try
            {            
                await Task.Delay(15000,token);
                token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
           
            }
            catch(Exception ex) 
            {
                Logger.Error(ex.GetBaseException().Message);
                //RedirectToAction("Trace", "D2");
            }
            finally
            {
                _tokenSource.Dispose();
            }
            return View(model);
        }
```

method being executed when ajax call for cancel button is triggered

```
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult CancelRequest()
        {
            _tokenSource.Cancel();
            return new EmptyResult();
        }
```

```
    function CancelRequest() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '@Url.Action("CancelRequest", "Trace")',
            success: function (results) {
                console.log(results);
                alert("Request Canceled");
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: I tried looking through various documentations but there is'nt a one parsing the cancellation token with an Ajax call to controller

Comment: There are a lot of errors with this code. `_tokenSource` is a private variable that is only in scope in the `Trace` method, you can't access it from `CancelRequest`. `IsCancellationRequested` returns a boolean, but you treat `token` like a `CancellationToken`.

Comment: @gunr2171 "*There are a lot of errors with this code. _tokenSource is a private variable that is only in scope in the Trace method, you can't access it from CancelRequest*" -- Why not? It's a field. You're right about `IsCancellationRequested` though

Comment: I missed that `_tokenSource` was defined earlier. Depending on the DI scope, that might be wiped with each request. Is there any reason you can't use a CancellationToken as a method parameter rather than making a source?

Comment: Errors in your question aside (which suggest the code you've given us isn't the code you're actually using), the problem is probably that each request gets a **new** instance of the controller. So `Trace` is being called on a **different** instance of the controller to `CancelRequest`, and so the `_tokenSource` field doesn't contain the CTS which was written by the call to `Trace`

Comment: I agree with @canton7 please post the code you're actually using. As it reads now, you're assigning a `bool` to `token` using `var token = _tokenSource.IsCancellationRequested` and then passing `await Task.Delay(15000, token)` which isn't going to compile. At the very least s.b. `var token = _tokenSource.Token`